# how to preserve element after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was trying to add element while button is clicked.but it is added when i click on button and it is gone just in 2 minutes.so how to set permenantly.following is code i tried.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d = "";
  $("input[name='submit']").click(function() {
    alert("button is clicked");
    d = $("select").val();
    alert("d====" + d);
    myfunction(d);
  });

  function myfunction(d) {
    if (d != "" && d != "undefined" && d != null) {
      for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        alert("hello");
        var d1 = "<div class='form-group'><label>Upload Image</label><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-picture-o'></i></span><input type='file' name=" + i + "class='form-control' placeholder='Upload your photo' id='img'></div></div>";
        $("#d2").append(d1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have `submit` button... Use `type = 'button'` as `submit` button will reload the page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I put submit button inside form element while clicking button it is post and page is loaded(refresh) and content is disabled....that's the reason.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

is your Submit button placed in a FORM tag?

i think it happens because when you click on a Submit button, your page redirects you to Target url

change your code like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d = "";
  $("input[name='submit']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("button is clicked");
    d = $("select").val();
    alert("d====" + d);
    myfunction(d);
  });

  function myfunction(d) {
    if (d != "" && d != "undefined" && d != null) {
      for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        alert("hello");
        var d1 = "<div class='form-group'><label>Upload Image</label><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-picture-o'></i></span><input type='file' name=" + i + "class='form-control' placeholder='Upload your photo' id='img'></div></div>";
        $("#d2").append(d1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

place this code inside document.ready block

```
$('form').submit(function ()
{
    return false;
});
```